# show different color on card by comparing issued and expiry date Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, date, frontend

I am showing one date i.e issued date which is I am getting from rest API, I am getting issued date and expiry date from API. what I need to do is compare the issued date and expiry date and show different background color.
Logic and code is below with API response
Expiry date
If the Expiry date is in Green color, it should mean that the card is well within its expiry (i.e. till six months left for the card to expire). Renew option will not be available in this case.
If the Expiry card is in Amber color, it should mean that the card is within 6 months of expiry or after expiry. Renew option will be available in this case.
If the Expiry date is in Red color, it should mean that the card is over 6 months past the expiry date. Renew option will not be available in this case.

API Response

```
{
    "data": [{
        "customerCardId": "J7dtdPoIMcIcMWOiSi1xXA==",
        "cardTypeName": "Basic Skills Card",
        "cardBackImageId": "+71GMR+l5/iE7c5xMaPmyg==",
    "cardFrontImageId": "+71GMR+l5/iE7c5xMaPmyg==",
    "cardExpiryDate": "2020-01-15T06:56:07.890+0000",
    "cardIssueDate": "2018-01-15T06:56:07.890+0000",
    "hasPhysicalCard": false,
    "isCardRenewable": true,
    "isPartnerCard": false,
    "occupationQualifications": [{
        "occupationId": "at92D45gZwLCd7uJvy+QrA==",
        "occupationName": "bricklaying",
        "qualificationId": "bct5lbkNpuWhL6uGwWDA5w==",
        "qualificationName": "Level 1 Diploma by City & Guilds",
        "awardingBodyId": "J7dtdPoIMcIcMWOiSi1xXA==",
        "awardingBodyName": "City & Guilds",
        "certificateNo": null,
        "certificateExpiryDate": null,
        "achievementDate": "1970-01-15T06:56:07.890+0000",
        "documents": []
    }]
}],
"totalRecords": 1,
"serviceResponseCode": "card-list-200",
"error": null
}            

<div class="cardWrap cardTypeList" *ngFor="let data of cardData; let i=index">

            <div class="cardHeader">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="headTitle col-sm-6">
                        <span class="imageIcon cardIcon"></span>
                        {{data.cardTypeName}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cardContent">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center cardTypeImg">
                            <img *ngIf="docId === ''" src="../../assets/images/person-1.jpg" alt="person" />
                            <img *ngIf="docId != ''" [src]="profileImage" alt="gold card" />
                        <div class="seeBack text-center">
                            <a *ngIf="imageSide" (click)="getfile(data.cardFrontImageId)" class="underLine">See Front</a>
                            <a *ngIf="!imageSide" (click)="getfile(data.cardBackImageId)"  class="underLine">See Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8 cardTypeContent">

                        <div class="expDate expgreen" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getExpiry(data.isCardRenewable)}">
                            Expiry Date
                            <strong >{{data.cardExpiryDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngFor="let qualificationdata of data.occupationQualifications">
                            <h6>Occupation</h6>
                            <p> {{qualificationdata.occupationName}}</p>
                            <h6>Qualification</h6>
                            <p> {{qualificationdata.qualificationName}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cardAction cardTypeAction">
                            <ul>
                                <li *ngIf=data.isCardRenewable class="updateCard">
                                    <div class="actionIcon">
                                        <a herf="#">Update Card</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li *ngIf=data.isCardRenewable class="renewCard">
                                    <div class="actionIcon">
                                        <a herf="#">Renew Card</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li *ngIf=data.isCardRenewable class="lostCard">
                                    <div class="actionIcon">
                                        <a herf="#">Lost Card</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li  *ngIf=data.hasPhysicalCard  class="lostCard">
                                        <div class="actionIcon">
                                            <a herf="#">Physical Card</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: and how the `getExpiry()` looks like?

Comment: Do you want [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eaadmxqgrggv)?

Comment: expiry and issued date i will get from API response given above

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that you can make the getExpiry method return a number depending on the result:

1. If it is within the expiration, returns 0.
2. If there are still 6 months left, return 1
3. If it has expired, return 2.

Then you change the call in the html that you make by:

```
<div class="expDate expgreen" [style.background-color]="getExpiry(data.isCardRenewable)=== 0 ? 'green': getExpiry(data.isCardRenewable)=== 1 ? 'yellow' : 'red'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function to get the expiry color should look like

```
getExpiry(expiryDate: Date, issuedDate: Date) {
    if(expiryDate < issuedDate)
        expiryColor = 'red'; //expired
    else if(expiryDate < issuedDate.setMonth(issuedDate).getMonth() + 6);
        expiryColor = 'yellow'; //about to expire within 6 minths
}
```

And use this color variable in your template as

```
[style.background-color]="expiryColor"
```

Comment: i need to compare the issued date with an expiry date that I am getting in above API response